# Vector field is parallel iff its derivative if orthogonal to the tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This is a question from Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, chapter 2: $M$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ with the induced metric and (I assume) the LC-conection and $V(t)$ some vector field along a differentiable curve $c(t)$. It asks  to show that $V$ is paralell iff the usual derivative $V'(t)$ is normal to the tangent plane $T_{c(t)}M$. Now, I know how to answer this using that the covariant derivative $\frac{DV}{dt}$ is the tangential component of $V'(t)$, but I want to work it out this way:

Choose an orthonormal basis of $T_{c(t)}M$ and let's say $X_1,X_2$ is the parallel transports of that basis along the curve. Say that $V = v_1X_1 + v_2 X_2$, since the basis is orthonormal we have that

$$V' = (v_1'X_1+v_2'X_2) + (v_1X_1'+v_2X_2') = \frac{DV}{dt} +(v_1X_1'+v_2X_2')$$

I'd like to show that $v_1X_1'+v_2X_2'$ is perpendicular to $T_{c(t)}M$ (and according to the other definition, it should be, for $\frac{DV}{dt} $ must account for the whole tangential part), but fail to. I know that $\langle X_i', X_i \rangle = 0$ for $i = 1,2$ but can't figure why $\langle X_i',X_j \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Somehow you translated the problem on $V$ to the same problem on $X_1,X_2$, but there's no escaping from what _parallel_ means. Describing the covariant derivative in $M$ as the tangential component of the covariant derivative in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as you mentioned) is one way to do it. Maybe you have some other description you wish to use here?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz the definition of a parallel I want to work with is that $\frac{DV}{dt} = 0$. That way, if $V$ is parallel $V' = v_1X_1'+v_2X_2'$ would be normal to the tangent plane, and vice versa.